# Solvability of linear elliptic PDE in unbounded domain.

Tags: partial-differential-equations, elliptic-operators

I am looking for references about the unique solvability of a linear elliptic second order pde in $\mathbb{R}^2$. We can assume that we have decaying conditions at infinity and that the operator is symmetric. The think is that Poincare inequality holds for bounded domains. Any ideas?

Comment: See if the Chapter 7 in the book "Nonlinear Parabolic
and Elliptic Equations" can help.